# Handle file upload not working in Primefaces 6.2

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I have recently updated Primefaces version to 6.2 and after doing that, I found that the file upload has stopped working. Below is my code:

```
<p:fileUpload label="Choose (Max. 5Mb)" fileUploadListener="#{action.handleFileUpload}" mode="advanced" dragDropSupport="false" sizeLimit="6553600"
fileLimit="1" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(xls|xlsx)$/" update=":dataUploadForm,:dataUploadForm:masterDataPanel" />
```

Java Code:

```
public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {
    try {
        UploadedFile uploadedFile = event.getFile();
        // do some processing
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        LOGGER_.error("", ex);
    }
}
```

As per the below image, when I click on Choose button, it opens the dialog box which allows to select the file and when I select the file and click on OK, nothing happens. But when I reload this page and then do the same operation, file gets uploaded successfully.

[image]

I was able to solve the issue by creating a variable of datatype "UploadedFile" in Bean and then modifying the method as below:

```
public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {
    try {
        UploadedFile uploadedFile = event.getFile();
        Bean.setUploadedFile(uploadedFile);
        // do some processing
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        LOGGER_.error("", ex);
    }
}
```

But I don't think this is the right approach, since when concurrent users will upload heavy files, the JVM might get stopped due to heavy load. Do we have any alternative to this problem?

Comment: I have no idea why the above fixed it but IMHO it is a bad idea to store the UploadedFile.  You should just immediately get the Contents stream from the uploaded file and store that but not the UploadFile itself.